# ng-grid: trigger a new search from select field

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm creating a search input that will search individual fields/columns in an ng-grid. (yes, I know ng-grid has its own way of doing this.)

I've got the search working, and I can search on individual fields, but the one piece I can't seem to figure out is how to re-trigger a search upon selecting a new field from the dropdown.

So: user searches fields 'Name' for 'blah', and gets some results.
Then user decides to search field 'Age'.
Search should *immediately* return any records that have 'blah' in the 'Age' field.

Here is my plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ryjp2ugmYWHcfvNdD7OZ?p=preview

(Try searching for 'ni' in the name field, then in the Age field. Ideally, I want to search Name to get Moroni, and then Age to get twenty nine). You can search on any field - as long as you choose the field FIRST - changing the field AFTER typing some search text doesn't work. In fact, I can't really seem to clear the search at all.

This part is my clumsy attempt to re-trigger the grid rendering, but I do not know where 'grid' and '$gridScope' come from:

```
  $scope.reSearch = function(){
    $scope.gridInit(grid, $gridScope);
  };
```

(You can see that I'm using gridInit. My page is pretty complex so I can't simplify the plunker any more than I have.)

Answer (score 1):

I advanced your code to the point that reSearch successfully calls gridInit again:
http://plnkr.co/edit/28bF6QBdRtfywA0YmUoV?p=preview

However, in this line, you are trashing your original data, so when you search again, you are only searching through the last search's results:

```
            $scope.myData = grid.filteredRows;
```

Comment: Thanks, although removing that line means that the grid doesn't update at all. I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: You need to save a copy of your original data to search through. I updated the plunker to show you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see what you've changed.

Comment: Sorry, I see a second dataset.  Not sure I follow. How would I implement this is an ajax-y environment?
Isn't that what this is doing?
$scope.myData = grid.filteredRows;

Comment: In a real environment, instead of copying the dataset, I would suggest doing a clone deep (you can use something like lodash for this) and assigning the clone to the search data. What you are doing in this line $scope.myData = grid.filteredRows; is trashing your original data. At that point, myData ONLY contains the results of your search, and you have nothing left that contains the full data set to search through. Look for mySearchData in my plunker to see how I used it in your filter function.

Comment: If you say so. The plunker works though, and there is no way you can assign $scope.myData = grid.filteredRows; and ever search reliably again.